# Spring Integration FTP Outbound gateway and remote folder permissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have an issue with fetching folders and files from the remote ftp server using Outbound gateway 'mget' function.

Here is the problem: Let's say we have folder tree /folder1/folder2/folderIWantToTransfer and I have 2 different user accounts. The first one has access to the whole folder tree. so I login via Filezilla to the FTP server and I can see /folder1/folder2/folderIWantToTransfe. In my spring ftp client I am able to specify the absolute path and everything works fine with this credentials. Then I have account 2 which has only access to folder2/folderIWantToTransfer, so when I login to Filezilla I see /folderIWantToTransfer. I am not able to see folders above so I can't provide the absolute folder path for the ftp client with this user credentials. It would be security issue to give access to those folder for other clients. I would expect when I use /folderIWantToTransfer as a path with those credentials then Spring's FTP client would download my folder, however nothing happens until I do not specify the absolute path to the folder.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try removing the leading `/` - use `folderIWantToTransfer`.

Comment: @Gary Russell, seems like the issue is not with access right and I also tried to specify path without /. Account 2 see the /folderIWantToTransfer only because the upper folders are empty. After checking the ftp server logs the client is executing the list command, but for some reason it does not fetch the data. I don't have the file copies in local directory and also the I tried to comment out the AcceptOnceFileListFilter